# How can I strip this URL of everything before "http://"?

Tags: regex, coldfusion, railo

I'm doing some web scraping with ColdFusion and mostly everything is working fine. The only other issues I'm getting is that some URL's come through with text behind them that is now causing errors.

Not sure what's causing it, but it's probably my regex. Anyhow, there's a distinct pattern where text appears before the "http://". I'd like to simply remove everything before it.

Any chance you could help?

**Take this string for example:**

```
"I'M OBSESSED WITH MY BEAUTIFUL FRIEND" src="http://scs.viceland.com/feed/images/uk_970014338_300.jpg
```

I'd much appreciate your help as regex isn't something I've managed to make time for - hopefully I will some day!

Thanks.

EDIT:

Hi,

I thought it might be helpful to post my entire function, since it could be my initial REGEX that is causing the issue. Basically, the funcion takes one argument. In this case, it's the contents of a HTML file (via CFHTTP).

In some cases, every URL looks and works fine. If I try digg.com for example it works...but it dies on something like youtube.com. I guess this would be down to their specific HTML formatting. Either way, all I ever need is the value of the SRC attribute on image tags.

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
<cffunction name="extractImages" returntype="array" output="false" access="public" displayname="extractImages">

        <cfargument name="fileContent" type="string" />

        <cfset var local = {} />
        <cfset local.images = [] />
        <cfset local.imagePaths = [] />
        <cfset local.temp = [] />

        <cfset local.images = reMatchNoCase("<img([^>]*[^/]?)>", arguments.fileContent) /> 

        <cfloop array="#local.images#" index="local.i">

            <cfset local.temp = reMatchNoCase("(""|')(.*)(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)", local.i) /> 

            <cfset local.path = local.temp />

            <cfif not arrayIsEmpty(local.path)>
                <cfset local.path = trim(replace(local.temp[1],"""","","all")) />
                <cfset arrayAppend(local.imagePaths, local.path) />
            </cfif>

            <cfif isValid("url", local.path)>

                <cftry>

                    <cfif fileExists(local.path)>
                        <cfset arrayAppend(local.imagePaths, local.path) /> 
                    </cfif>

                    <cfcatch type="any">
                        <cfset application.messagesObject.addMessage("error","We were not able to obtain all available images on this page.") />
                    </cfcatch>

                </cftry>

            </cfif>

        </cfloop>

        <cfset local.imagePaths = application.udfObject.removeArrayDuplicates(local.imagePaths) />

        <cfreturn local.imagePaths />

    </cffunction>
```

This function WORKS. However, on some sites, not so. It looks a bit over the top but much of it is just certain safeguards to make sure I get valid image paths.

Hope you can help.

Many thanks again.
Michael

Comment: Well, what is your current regex?

Comment: you should probably be looking for all text within your "src" variables.  That would be an easy way to do it.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the reply. I just updated my post with my function in question. Hopefully that helps? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, my logic was wrong. I should have used the isValid() function earlier on to filter out the malformed results. Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at ReFind() or REFindNoCase() - http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#refindnocase

Here is a regex that will work.

```
<cfset string = 'IM OBSESSED WITH MY BEAUTIFUL FRIEND" src="http://scs.viceland.com/feed/images/uk_970014338_300.jpg' />

<cfdump var="#refindNoCase('https?://[-\w.]+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_.]*)?)?',string, 1, true)#">
```

You will see a structure returned with a POS and LEN keys. Use the first element in the POS array to see where the match starts, and the first element in the LEN array to see how long it is. You can then use these values in the Mid() function to grab just that matching URL.

Comment: Thanks. Your code was helpful and in turn sent me on a path to solve the issue. You get the prixe! Cheers :)

Comment: @Michael - You might also try @Scott's expression with `reMatchNoCase()`. It returns an array of matched strings. It is not always as good as `reFind` when it comes to stuff like non-capturing groups. But give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ColdFusion, but it seems to me that you just need a regex that looks for http://, then any number of characters, then the end of the string.

Comment: Yes that's pretty much it, but believe me...I don't even know how to do that. :(

Comment: Okay - I can't be of any help there, I know nothing about ColdFusion :)